# Problem inside for loop joining string with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this maybe a simple problem for some, but i really don´t know what´s the problem here. Inside a simple for loop i have this:

```
for (i = 0; i < r.foto.length; i++) 
{
  let slide = '<a href=../img/'+ r.foto[i] +'>' + '<img src=../img/thumb/'+ r.fotoThumbArray[i]+'>' + '</a>';
}
```

This is suppose to get photos that i have in my database, and the strange error that appears is in the console:

```
GET http://basedados.test/img/thumb/thumbqZSxpYVJevWz0PMR.jpeg%22 404 (Not Found)
```

**I don´t understand why it appears that %22 in the end of the GET method**, any guesses?

Regards

Comment: `%22` is `"`. So, it sounds like you have an extra `"` in your `foto[i]` or in your `fotoThumbArray[i]`. Mind logging the array and posting the result? Thanks.

Comment: To add to briosheje see [HTML URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information about characters like `%22`.

Comment: you have to write href="", the " are missing in your string

Comment: `r.foto.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => \`<a href=../img/${x}><img src=../img/thumb/${r.fotoThumbArray[xi]}></a>\`, '');`

Answer (score 1):

%22 is due to URL Encoding of characters that do not fall under the ASCII Character set. URLs can only be sent over the internet by converting any such characters by encoding them.

Refer this:- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < r.foto.length; i++) 
{
  let slide = '<a href="../img/'+ r.foto[i] +'">' + '<img src="../img/thumb/'+ r.fotoThumbArray[i]+'">' + '</a>';
}
```

Comment: This would not change anything, because the extra quote mark is in `r.fotoThumbArray[i]`. Also, answers which explain how their changes are meant to fix the problem are better than those which simply show code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help, **briosheje** was right, i was saving the image with extra characters.